# What is $\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} ({x^2+y^2})^{x^2y^2}$?

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

Can someone help me with finding this limit? I tried to use trigonometric way for solution -  $x = r \sin t$, $y = r \cos t$, but obtained $1$; the real answer must be $0$. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is $\lim_{x \to 0+} x^x$?

Comment: That llimense is equal to 1

Comment: Nevermind my comment. It is of nu use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take log we have: $x^2y^2\ln(x^2+y^2)= r^4\sin^2\theta\cos^2\theta\ln(r^2) = r^2\sin^2\theta\cos^2\theta(r^2\ln(r^2)) \to 0$ because $t\ln t \to 0$ when $t \to 0$. So the original limit is $1$ .

Comment: So wolfram is wrong ? 

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lim+%28x%5E2+%2B+y%5E2%29%5E%28x%5E2*y%5E2%29+as+%28x%2Cy%29-%3E%280%2C0%29

Comment: It is not wrong. The one you gave it is $(x^2+y^2)^{x^2}$ and it is markedly different from the one here.

Comment: You copied the whole link ? because some part of link is cutted

Comment: Oh, sorry, my fault )

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**: use polar coordinates:
$$(x^2+y^2)^{x^2y^2}=(r^2)^{r^4\cos^2\theta\sin^2\theta}=\mathrm e^{r^4\cos^2\theta\sin^2\theta\,\ln(r^2)}.$$

Comment: I prefer your solution to mine. Elegant!

Comment: Thank you for your kind appreciation. Yours is quite ingenious!

Answer (score 3):

For any sequence $(x_n, y_n) \rightarrow (0, 0)$, let $z_n = \max \{|x_n|, |y_n| \}$ and $t_n = \min \{|x_n|, |y_n| \}$.
\begin{aligned}
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \ln((x_n^2 + y_n^2)^{x_n^2 y_n^2}) 
&= \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} x_n^2 y_n^2 \ln(x_n^2 + y_n^2) \\
&= \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} z_n^2 t_n^2 \ln(z_n^2 + t_n^2) \\
&\leq \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} z_n^2 t_n^2 \ln(2 z_n^2) \\
&= \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} t_n^2 \cdot \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} z_n^2 \ln(2 z_n^2) \\
&= 0
\end{aligned}
The limit is also non-negative, so it is $0$.
Back to the original question, we have
$$\lim_{(x, y) \rightarrow (0,0)} (x^2 + y^2)^{x^2 y^2} = 1$$

Comment: Hi. $\log (x^2+y^2) \le \log (2z^2)$ √. Multiplying by $x^2y^2:$ $x^2y^2 \log(x^2+y^2) \le x^y^2\log (2z^2)$ √.Does it follow $x^2y^2 \log (2z^2) \le z^4\log(2z^2)$. Note:  $0\le x^y^2 \le z^4,$ and the logs are negative. Your thoughts?

Comment: @PeterSzilas, thanks, nice catch! I patched the solution with both max and min. Hope it is working now.

Comment: Looks better:) Greetings.